# Google Analytics URL for event tracking

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm tracking several pages with Google Analytics. Each page uses a custom URL passed to _trackPageView:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/someurl']);
```

(Our site uses the same URL on every page, so I'm stuck with using a virtual URL to identify every page).

This all works fine, but I'm noticing that the virtual URL isn't being associated with any events I later track on the same pages. The events are recorded just fine, but if I view the Events->Pages section in the standard reports, the page URL shown is the main URL for the site, not my virtual URL. So in my case every event ends up being associated with the same URL for the site, instead of the '/someurl' defined earlier.

I'm not doing anything special with the event tracking code, just the usual `_gaq.push( [ "_trackEvent", ... ] );`

I have a few user timings, and they are showing the same behaviour.

Does anyone know if I can specify a virtual URL to send along with a event?

Comment: Are you calling `_trackPageview` before the events are tracked?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if you've already considered this, but how about you add the virtual url to the event label and distinguish between events on different pages that way?